# ASP.net placing database model numbers into an array

Tags: asp.net, mysql, arrays, gridview

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to add some of my model numbers from my database to am array while looping.

This is my code:

```
objCmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()

If dtReader.HasRows() Then
   grdViewItems.DataSource = dtReader
   grdViewItems.DataBind()

   Dim arrayOfItems As String() = New String() {}

   While dtReader.Read()
        arrayOfItems(intX) = dtReader.GetString("model_number")
        'arrayItems(intX) = dtReader.GetString("model_number")
        intX += 1
   End While

   'Session.Add("arrayOfItems", arrayItems)
   Session("arrayOfItems") = arrayOfItems

   dtReader.Close()
   dtReader = Nothing
   objConn.Close()
   objConn = Nothing
End If
```

Problem being that it never populates the array with the values (although the values are present in the gridview because it skips the reading of the values in the while loop.

What am i doing incorrectly here?

**Complete code**

```
Dim intX As Integer = 0

    objConn = New MySqlConnection(product.strConnString)
    objConn.Open()

    strSQL = "SELECT prod.id, PP.model_number, description, price, price_new, price_direct, price_builder " & _
             "FROM product as prod " & _
                "INNER JOIN product_price as PP ON PP.product_id = prod.type " & _
             "WHERE prod.id = " & pageID & ";"

    Try
        objCmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
        dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If dtReader.HasRows() Then
            grdViewItems.DataSource = dtReader
            grdViewItems.DataBind()

            Dim arrayOfItems As New List(Of String)()

            For Each row As GridViewRow In grdViewItems.Rows
                arrayOfItems(intX) = row.Cells(0).Text.ToString
                intX = intX + 1
            Next

            MsgBox(arrayOfItems(0))

            'Session.Add("arrayOfItems", arrayItems)
            Session("arrayOfItems") = arrayOfItems

            dtReader.Close()
            dtReader = Nothing
            objConn.Close()
            objConn = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("LoadProductItems: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: try dtReader.GetString(index of column) method

Comment: i think you are missing the cast. `  arrayItems(intX) dtReader("model_number")` check it

Comment: Also it seems to be skipping the **Do While dtReader.Read**?? Would that be because it already read all the values in **grdViewItems.DataSource = dtReader**?

Comment: no, the data still presents in the dtReader. Place a break point at this location `arrayItems(intX) = dtReader("model_number")` and check whether data is assigned to the array or not

Comment: and what is arrayItems type is it of int or string or object ?

Comment: ok. and i think dtReader("model_number") returns object if yes then you have to call the dtReader("model_number").ToString() method.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: It never goes into the loop. It reads the line **Do While dtReader.Read** and skips and goes straight to **Session("arrayOfItems") = arrayOfItems**. I also updated the code that i am working with right now in the OP.

Comment: see my answer. so the problem is in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array, I would recommend using [List of int or string](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Wont work to pull out the values in the session :o(

Comment: Also it seems to be skipping the **Do While dtReader.Read**?? Would that be because it already read all the values in **grdViewItems.DataSource = dtReader**?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your loop. Replace the following code

```
Do While dtReader.Read
   arrayOfItems(intX) = dtReader.GetString("model_number")
   intX += 1
Loop

'with this code
While dtReader.Read()
     arrayOfItems(intX) = dtReader.GetString("model_number")
     intX += 1
End While
```

**Updated Answer:**
When you assign data to gridview then also save the data in a datatable like this

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt = dtReader

`Then get the data from the table
Dim i As Integer = 0
Do While (i < dt.Rows.Count)
dt.Rows(i)("COlumnName").ToString
i = (i + 1)
Loop
```

**Again Updated Answer:**
Read the data from the gridview

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In grdViewItems.Rows
   arrayOfItems(intX) = row.Cells(0).Text.ToString ` in cell specify the index of the model_number column
   intX = intX + 1
Next
```

Comment: Still skips over it.. And i know i am getting a value because i have checked the SQL query it uses. **Edited my OP with the new code**

Comment: When i comment out both the **grdViewItems.DataSource = dtReader** and the **grdViewItems.DataBind()** the loop works. Although there is an error stating **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Comment: dtReader is a **MySqlConnection**

Comment: what ? how's that possible. You are doing something wrong. Show the complete code of dtReader

Comment: Updated my OP with full code. There is an error on line **dataTable = dtReader** saying **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable**

Comment: ok I understood. Leave it. Read the data from the gridview. I updated my answer. check it and let me know.

Comment: Ok i updated it with your new code in the OP. Again, i am getting an error of **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection** on the line **arrayOfItems(intX) = row.Cells(0).Text.ToString**

Comment: mention the index of model_number. It may be 0,1 or 2 etc. In gridview model_number column is show at which number ? If first col then index should be 0 if second column then index should be 1 and so......`arrayOfItems(intX) = row.Cells(index of column).Text.ToString()`